# Math Range Error: Overflow Error using numpy.power()

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using Python 3 to use scipy's integrate.quad() function to integrate the expression (t^s / cosh^2(t))
for a given input s. I get the OverflowError: math range error.

My code looks like this:

```
from math import inf
from math import cosh
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np

def Integral_Expression(s):
    ans, err = quad(lambda t: (np.power(t,s))/(np.power(cosh(t),2)), 0, inf)
    return ans
```

I've seen other people who get the Math Range Error use numpy's exp() or power() methods to solve the problem, but it doesn't seem to be working. I also tried

```
and, err = decimal.Decimal(quad(lambda t: (power(t,s))/power(cosh(t),2), 0, inf))
```

with no success. Thanks for any help!

Comment: what range of `s` do you consider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great chance that the problem comes from the square of `cosh(t)` that behaves like an exponential for `t` close to infinity. Maybe you can stop the upper bound of the integral to `100` given that `1/cosh(100)**2=5e-87` you are already reaching the floating point precision.

Note that you'll get the same error if you simply try to evaluate `cosh(1000)` in your python code:

```
print(cosh(1000))
```

Output:

```
% python3 script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(cosh(1000))
OverflowError: math range error
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution). Try to change variable to something that does not grow so rapidly like `cosh(x)`.

Try:

```
t = log(u)
```

Now:

```
cosh(t) = 0.5 *  (exp(t) + exp(-t)) = 0.5 * (u + 1/u)
dt = du / u
```

After the change, the old integral

```
Integral[(t**s)/cosh(t)**2, 0, Inf]
```

becomes

```
Integral[log(u)**s/((u+1/u)/2)**2/u, 1, inf]
```

Note that integral boundaries had changed as well.

The result:

```
s = 2
quad(lambda u: (log(u)**s)/((u+1/u)/2)**2/u, 1, inf)
```

returns `(0.8224670334241126, 1.1430967283843074e-11)`.

This solution is slightly more precise than approach based on replacing infinity with a large number:

```
>>> quad(lambda t: (t**s)/cosh(t)**2, 0, 100)
(0.8224670334241144, 1.3879318674935893e-08)
```